# Getting the same values 2 times in console,angular2

Tags: html, angular

When i am seeing the data that comes from form in console it get two times

My template

```
   <div class="login jumbotron center-block">
   <h1>Login</h1>
  <form  #form ="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="username">Username</label>
     <input type="text" ngControl ="email" class="form-control" id="emailh" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input type="password"  ngControl ="phone" class="form-control" id="phoneh" placeholder="Password">
 </div>
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <a [routerLink]="['/signup']">Click here to Signup</a>
</form>
</div>
```

My component,

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
  import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
  import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
  import { contentHeaders } from '../headers/headers';
   import {Control,FormBuilder,ControlGroup,Validators} from '@angular/common';
 @Component({

 directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
templateUrl : "./components/login/login.html",

 })
 export class Login {

 constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
 }

 onSubmit(form:any) {

   console.log(form);
 }
  }
```

my console,

```
 Object {email: "andrew@gmail.com", phone: "getiyt"}
 Object {email: "andrew@gmail.com", phone: "getiyt"}
```

When i am seeing the data that comes from form in console it get two times,therefor i am not sure that why it comes like that as a result my db also get filled with single record 2 times.Can someone find where i am wrong.

Comment: How does it work if you remove `type="submit"` from the `<button>`?

Comment: no change in the console

Comment: I guess it should just work. Can you provide a [Plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html) to make it easier to investigate?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FrpxRJJMVgIZVAVKeueq?p=catalogue

Comment: Can you please use the Plunker link I posted in my previous comment and add your code there. Your Plunker is not runnable.

Comment: I am not able to save the code in plunker

Comment: can u please copy the code above to plunker

Comment: I can't reproduce http://plnkr.co/edit/E8jyBriMKUlljEzMWpsU?p=preview

Comment: i addead  http://plnkr.co/edit/gscsLhhLG3Wo4oDy05sY?p=preview

Comment: Is there a difference to my Plunker? I still can't reproduce.

Comment: Also cant reproduce error. Only seeing one log in console.

Comment: i am failed to use plunker

Comment: You should consider renaming the question to "Form submit function fires two times on one click, angular 2" or something like this. Btw: having the same problem here.

Comment: As said, having the same problem here. After some tests, I decided to post a bug report in the repo. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9954

Answer (score 1):

In your main.ts you have to set:

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()]);
```

This solve the problem. See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uiYZkEWMyXWOkglHZu6N

See also the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Credit: Roberto Simonetti's [answer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9954) here.

Comment: Hi @Samuel,still i am facing the same error after adding the above steps

Comment: I tried now with my code and it just works perfectly.

Comment: Hi @Samuel,the console is still showing the same results